# `pip install fastparquet` fails with "Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.11')" but `pip install numpy==1.11` suceeds

Tags: python, docker, pip

Trying to `pip3 install fastparquet` package in a Docker image (where I first `sudo apt install python3` and set pip.conf to use a company internal package repository) gives me

```
Step 6/6 : RUN pip3 install fastparquet
 ---> Running in 2dd7fb7de45e
Looking in indexes: https://anon.artifactory.internal.net/api/pypi/ext-pypi/simple, https://anon.artifactory.internal.net/api/pypi/gr-pypi/simple
Collecting fastparquet
  Downloading https://anon.artifactory.internal.net/api/pypi/ext-pypi/packages/packages/c2/3e/970dcb3605c1d406be9304f00895bf89ca6b71162afa7f95c5a4032bf927/fastparquet-0.5.0.tar.gz (120 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ijksg7gm/fastparquet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ijksg7gm/fastparquet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-p1c1xxm6
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ijksg7gm/fastparquet/
    Complete output (25 lines):
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'numpy' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for numpy>=1.11
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ijksg7gm/fastparquet/setup.py", line 98, in <module>
        **extra
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 128, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 123, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 513, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 774, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1057, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1069, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 580, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 692, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.11')
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.4; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Removing intermediate container 2dd7fb7de45e

The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install fastparquet' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

If I instead `pip3 install numpy==1.11`, there is no problem.

If I first upgrade pip3, then `pip3 install fastparquet` works but `pip3 install fastparquet==0.3.2` gives the same error.

Comment: It seems that `Name or service not known` is the actual problem. Are you using Alpine as the base image? Some name resolution problems were present on Alpine image according to [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/resolved-service-name-resolution-broken-on-alpine-and-docker-1-11-1-cs1/19307).

Comment: @AliTou I figured the problem is that pip even tried to look up the package in the internet. It should look it up in the artifactory

Comment: I'm not using Alpine, btw

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by first installing setuptools==42.0.0, which switched to using pip to resolve `setup_requires` (https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v42-0-0). (fastparquet uses `setup_requires` to install numpy before its installed itself)